# Cannot acces an any host user from my phpMyAdmin ,xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have an error with my **phpmyadmin**.When I create any host user and the trying to login with this user it's still saying to me "`Cannot log in to the MySQL server`"

I have tryed to create same account with the same privilages&password and choosing localhost but the same error.Any help please?

PS:I'm using the **Ultimate XAMPP Version**.

The users configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ANY users from database.It should look like this
[image]

Comment: Ok,it works,thanks!I think the new user can connect now her server to my db using my public ip...